# How to get all pages text from pdf pag(links) using selenium IDE and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get text from PDF pages for that I am going to hit pdf page link one by one using XPATH selenium IDE and python But it gives me empty data, **Sometimes It gives me one page content of PDF** page but not in a particular format.

How can I get text from all pages of pdf link?

**Here is My code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

url = "http://www.incredibleindia.org"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url) 
# wait for menu to being loaded
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu li > a")))

#article under media tab 
article_link = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in   driver.find_elements_by_xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[6]/a")]
#all important news links under trade tab 
for link in article_link:
    print link
    driver.get(link) 
    #check article sublinks css available on article link page
    try:
         WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.article-full-div")))
    except TimeoutException:
         print driver.title, "No news links under media tab"
    #alrticle sub links under article tab 
    article_sub_links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in   driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='article-content']/div/div[2]/ul/li/a")]

    print "article sub links"
    for link in article_sub_links:
        print link

        driver.get(link)  
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.textLayer")))
        except TimeoutException:
            print driver.title, "No news links under media tab"

        content = [a.text for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'pageContainer')]")] 
        print content 
        for data in content:
            print data
```

**Output:**

```
http://www.incredibleindia.org/en/media-black-2/articles
article sub links
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Ajanta.pdf
[u'', u'', u'']



http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Bedhaghat.pdf
404 - Error: 404 No news links under media tab` 
[]
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Bellur.pdf
[u'', u'', u'']



http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Bidar.pdf
[u'', u'', u'']



http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Braj.pdf
[u'', u'', u'', u'']




http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Carnival.pdf
[u'', u'', u'']`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go down to the "textlayer" (`div` element with `class="textlayer"` inside each page container). You also need to use `continue` in exception handling blocks:

```
for link in article_sub_links:
    driver.get(link)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.textLayer")))
    except TimeoutException:
        print driver.title, "Empty content"
        continue

    content = [a.text for a in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[id^=pageContainer] div.textLayer")]
    for data in content:
        print data
```

Comment: It is working on some pdf links but not for all pdf links. It is printing pdf links or content of some pdf links, not content of the all pdf link.

Comment: @user3902208 thanks, could you provide an example link which this is not working for?

Comment: Output:
`http://www.incredibleindia.org/en/media-black-2/articles
article sub links
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Ajanta.pdf
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Bedhaghat.pdf
404 - Error: 404 Empty content
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Bellur.pdf
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Gir.pdf
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Hampi.pdf
http://www.incredibleindia.org/images/articles/Orchha.pdf **It did not show content except this link**`

Comment: @user3902208 not sure it would help, but try changing `presence_of_element_located` to `visibility_of_element_located`.